# MSSQL generating a column with rows dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hope you all have a fantastic time!

I am trying to create a temporary column with date values from the past 14 days.

so in essence, it should for example the below list whenever i re-call this stored procedure:

[image]

Reason for this is that we might not have data for a specific date, and we need to show that the count returns zero.

So the idea is to create a column, and then join with another table i created based on the date to do the counts per day.

I tried below code, but it does not work:

```
declare @a int
set @a = 1

select

    [Date] = while (@a <= 14)
            begin
            cast(dateadd(day, -@a, getdate()) as date)
            set @a = @a + 1
            end

into #Temp1


select

*

from #Temp1
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to utilise a `tally / numbers` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simulated numbers table in a `cte` (you would ideally have a permanent table) you can simply do

```
with numbers as (
    select top (14) Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) as n from sys.sysobjects
)
select cast(dateadd(day, -n, getdate()) as date)
from numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying `sys.sysobjects` unnecessarily, you can generate the table **on the fly with no reads**, by using a `VALUES` constructor.

```sql
with numbers as (
    select Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) as n
    from (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) v(x)
)
select cast(dateadd(day, -n, getdate()) as date)
from numbers
```